# What happens in terms of call stacks when 10000 setTimeouts are called?

Tags: compiler, asynchronous-programming, callbacks

Say we call 10000 setTimeouts, each with a random time, each with a few nested timeouts too. What happens in terms of the 1 call stack, or are there multiple call stacks? How does that work?

So for example:

```
let i = 0
while (i++ < 10000) {
  process(`process ${i}`, randomBetween(5, 30))
}

function process(name, timeout) {
  console.log(`${name} called`)
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(`${name} timeout called`)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${name} nested timeout 1 called`)
    }, 25)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${name} nested timeout 2 called`)
    }, 30)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${name} nested timeout 3 called`)
    }, 15)
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${name} nested timeout 4 called`)
    }, 5)
  }, timeout)
}

function randomBetween(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
}
```

I get how callbacks, event loops, and async work. But I don't understand the data structure used to implement the callstack(s) in this case. What would it look like, how would it work?

I am asking because I want to implement this feature in a custom programming language, and am having difficulty imagining what the structure is of the callstack(s) under the hood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Phillip's answer said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/422242/3733), all the answers were basically up to how you design your execution model, there are various tradeoffs between different execution model. That said, if you're modeling your execution model similar to JavaScript, there are a couple things we do know with JavaScript.

JavaScript uses an execution model that boils down to single threaded operation with an event queue. At the heart of this is the event queue, which is implemented using a [priority queue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) with scheduled time as the priority/sorting key and an infinite loop that pops items off the priority queue called the event loop (sometimes also called [trampoline](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing))). A priority queue is just like regular queue, except you don't just push items to the back of the queue, but you insert the item in their position as determined by the sorting key. Efficient implementation of priority queue usually uses either a [heap data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), a tree, or [skip list](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) to maintain partial sorting without having to actually constantly re-sort the queue as items gets pushed and popped into the queue very frequently.

The event loop is basically just an infinite loop that peeks at the scheduled execution time of the item at the front of the queue and optionally sleeps until the scheduled time, when it returns from sleeping, it pops the front of the queue and executes its callback, this repeats forever until the loop is closed. Any of the callback can push item to the queue, either to be executed "immediately" (i.e. it's pushed with scheduled time that immediately expires, so it'll run after all the other events that has also expired), or with future scheduled time such as when using `setTimeout()`/`setInterval()` with non-zero time.

Additionally, there are also hardware events like mouse clicks, typing into the keyboard, network events, and filesystem events, that may also schedule items into the queue asynchronously; in this case, the event queue may have to handle an interrupted sleep, respond to the hardware event, and then reschedule another sleep. Also, in some languages, the execution model may also have a mechanism to specify the priority of events, so higher priority tasks always gets precedence over lower priority tasks that expires at the same time.

The call stack is implemented, unsurprisingly, using a [stack data structure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)), containing local variable contexts and any other information needed to resume when returning from a function call. There's the simple stack data structure that you might have been taught at CompSci classes, but you probably are also hardware stack that allows your CPU to return from a function call opcode. Depending on the design of your language, you may want to use either a hardware or software stack.

The basic principle between hardware and software stack are basically the same, you push and pop item to the top of the stack. Whenever you call a function, you push a new local variable contexts to the stack and the return address, and whenever you return from a function you pop off the top of the stack and jump into the return address. The only main difference is that with hardware stack you have to use the low level CPU instructions which will manage the call stack implicitly and automatically.

JavaScript execution model is single threaded, which means that a single JavaScript execution context is allocated a single real OS thread. Recent version of JavaScript also has async functions/coroutines which mimicks the execution of a thread, so the language can track multiple threads of execution without using real OS thread and the overhead associated with real context switching. This is also called [green threading](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads).

At the most basic level, coroutines just means that you're switching the current call stack's base pointer without actually doing a full thread context switching (which involves saving state of the CPU registers and setting up a bunch of hardware timer interrupts to preempt the thread if it didn't yield the execution).

Without coroutines, a single OS thread usually have a single hardware stack, and languages that uses single threaded execution model uses the event loop to trampoline the concurrent execution between multiple callbacks. With green threads/coroutines, that trampoline will also switch the call stacks.

Comment: This doesn't explain how the call-stack works in a complicated case like this. I don't see how the call-stack can handle this tree-like branching and still be called a "stack". It seems like a tree. Please explain that.

Comment: @Lance Pollard: There's no tree-like branching. It's just a simple stack, there's no branching or anything like that in the call stack. The trick to handle "branches" as you called it, or using more standard term "green threads", isn't in the call stack data structure, but in the event loop mechanism. By using a trampoline, you can serialise multiple "branches" without actually needing to do anything special in the call stack. It's all just a series of events, no matter how nested they are, the trampoline just switches between different coroutines/callbacks to create the illusion.

Comment: @LancePollard You night also be confusing the function call stack with the [function closures](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)). Basically, in languages that supports closures, callbacks aren't just pointer to a function, but also contain a pointer to its lexical context. When an inner function is created/bound, that function captures references to the enclosing context to allow non-local variable resolution and to allow those variables to outlive its original call.

Comment: @Lance Pollard: Captured variables using closures are usually implemented by allocating captured variables in dynamically allocated memories rather than as automatic variables in the stack as is normally the case for local variables. There are also languages that simulates real closures by copying the non-local variables when creating the inner function.

Comment: @LancePollard - even in a single-threaded scenario, methods calls in a program form a tree, but the call stack doesn't encode the tree, it just helps traverse it. It's a scratchpad recording where you've been. It's not the responsibility of the call stack to know where to go next - other code causes calls to be made and stack frames to be pushed on it. `setTimeout()` just stores the callback in the priority queue, returns *immediately* and is *popped off* the call stack. The event loop later on checks the top item in the queue and makes a *new call* (to the callback) if it timed out.

Comment: @LancePollard Forget about setTimeout. Do you know how the call stack works when you do `function f() {g1(); g2(); g3(); g4(); g5(); g6();}`? How does it handle this tree-like branching?

Answer (score 6):

For your custom programming language, the answer is "whatever you want it to be". Once you've defined your [execution model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Execution_model), that will tell you what your call stacks look like. In particular here, you will need to decide whether your language has pre-emptive or cooperative concurrency. Unless you've already had those thoughts, you're jumping the gun by asking questions about a JavaScript-like `setTimeout` function, as that's a concept which makes sense only in certain execution models.

That all said, if your execution model is something like JavaScript's "single threaded with event loop" model, a simple implementation would be something like:

1. `setTimeout` is called 10k times. This will add 10k entries to a set<sup>1</sup> of pending callbacks somewhere in the language runtime somewhere of the form `(runAt: <some time>, functionToRun: <someFunction>)`.
2. Once the event loop is idle, the runtime will look at the set of pending callbacks created in step 1, pick one of them<sup>2</sup> for which `currentTime >= runAt` and run it. This may add some more entries to the set of pending callbacks.
3. Once the chosen callback has run to completion, repeat step 2.

At some point, your program will run out of work to do and can then either terminate or wait for an external trigger which schedules more work. Again, a decision for your execution model.

So *in a JavaScript-like execution model*, there is only ever one call stack, with the rest of the state being stored in data structures. But again: you can do something completely different in your programming language if you want.

<sup>Notes:

1. A set in the mathematical sense of "a group of things" rather than the programming sense.
 
2. If multiple callbacks are eligible to be run, it's again up to your execution model which one is run.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

Further continuing that thought ...

Timer queues might be built using some kind of *tree* data structure, with the key value being the time-of-day that the event is supposed to run.  (Trees simplify the process of inserting new values at any position needed.)  The timer-runner examines the lowest-valued node of the tree to determine if the event should occur.  If so, the node is removed from the tree, the handler routine is called, and the node is discarded.

The timer-runner might be a thread, allowing it to `sleep()` until the next event is to occur.  (This thread must also be awakened if anyone makes any modification to the tree.)  Each time it wakes up, it looks *again* to find what is the next timeout to be run.  Each active timeout is simply a node in the tree.  A mutex is used to ensure that the tree contents are checked or modified by only one process/thread at a time.

Unsurprisingly, "timer runners" are by now a "stock software part," readily available off-the-shelf at places like github.

Comment: This doesn't attempt to answer the question, but instead seems to be an extended comment on another answer.